# Case with reading from JSP textarea

Tags: java, database, jsp, servlets

I have web app on Tomcat, and on one of my page I want to make ability to write a big articles in textarea and then save them to my db in the Clob type field. But I can't read full of this article for inserting in my table, because `request.getParameter()` returns String, but article can have length more. Can you advise how to solve this case?

Answer (score 0):

`getParameter()` is perfectly fine for the job. It will for sure return all the content of the `textarea`.
If you absolutely need a `Clobe` object you'll need to construct it and set the string.

```
final CLOB clob = oracleConnection.createClob();
clob.setString(index, myString);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to ask you one question. If I understand right, String has length = Max.Integer, but if my article would be bigger will 'getParameter()'  work? Or it read only part?

Comment: I highly doubt that someone will ever put 2147483647 characters in a textarea. But anyway, yeah, it will be truncated. You could set a max length on the HTML spec.

Comment: Thak you very much. I think yes String is enough.

Comment: It's enough for sure!